# Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3を用いたHDR画像のraw画像取得方法

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry PiでRaspberry Pi Camera Module 3を用いてHDR画像のraw画像を取得したいと考えているのですが取得は可能なのでしょうか。
また、取得できる場合はどのような形式で、どのようなコードにより取得が可能であるのかを教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ここ [Buy a Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 – Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/camera-module-3/) を見ると`Output: RAW10`とだけあるので、`RAW10`という形式の一択でしょう。そしてこんなQ&A記事 [Raspberry Pi Camera Module v3 with legacy camera stack](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=350820) があるので、`modern libcamera`とか`libcamera-based Picamera2 beta under Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye`というのを探してみてはどうでしょう？